# Application HA in k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

im trying to make my app **HA**, so I created the following

1. 3 replica
2. PDB
3. liveness and readiness probes and
4. pod anti affinity

is there anything else which I miss?

this is the antiaffinty config

```
...
affinity:
podAntiAffinity:
requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
- labelSelector:
matchLabels:
app.kubernetes.io/name: ten
topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
- weight: 100
podAffinityTerm:
labelSelector:
matchLabels:
app.kubernetes.io/name: tan
topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
```

Is there anything I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly Available.. I think these are the parameters for an application to be HA..

1. Never launch your app directly from a Pod - it won’t survive a crash of a node. Even for single pod applications use **ReplicaSet** or **Deployment** objects, as they manage pods across whole cluster and maintain specified number of instances (even if it’s only one)
2. Use **affinity configuration** with custom rules to spread your pods based on your environments architecture. Workload are running in multiple instances spread across multiple nodes provides second level of resilience to the app
3. Define a **livenessProbe** for each container. Use proper method. Avoid ExecAction when your container can process HTTP requests. Remember to set proper initialDelaySeconds parameter to give your app some time to initialize (especially for ones based on JVM like Spring Boot - they are slow to start their HTTP endpoints)

You seemingly following all these points, so you should be good.

4. However If feasible I would recommend to try to deploy the apps on **multiple clusters** OR say deploy across multiple data centres and run in active-active mode. It can help adding more more nines to your availability.

Answer (score 1):

- Resource limit

You need to add the resource limit also in workloads it's a necessary thing otherwise cronjobs or other unnecessary workloads can may impact the business logic and workloads.

- HPA - POD autoscaling

There is also some chance of all three POD get killed due to readiness & liveness while the workload under heavy traffic and the application won't be able to respond to readiness & liveness in this I would suggest you implement the HPA also at the place.

Comment: "and the application won't be able to respond to readiness & liveness" --- then it's a bug that should be fixed. HPA wouldn't solve the core of the problem, it would just produce even more dead pods.

Comment: @zerkms - so do you think I miss anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

HA can be achieved by using multiple replicas, kubernetes provides this feature for HA only. Further service object in kubernetes helps load balancing the traffic to one of the available replicas based on liveliness and readiness probes, both of which are responsible for identifying the pod as healthy and ready to receive requests, resp.
please refer here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/